# DATE(timestamp_expression[, timezone]) in Bigquery: convert UTC (2021-12-07T04:46:16Z) to local time, UTC has T and Z in SQL. How to get AEST?

Tags: google-bigquery, utc

I am first removing T, Z. then converting to TIMESTAMP and converting to AEST.

```
SELECT firstSignUpDate_rev,
TIMESTAMP(SAFE_CAST(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', firstSignUpDate_rev)as DATETIME), 'Australia/Sydney')
FROM 
(SELECT firstSignUpDate,
REGEXP_REPLACE(firstSignUpDate, 'T|Z', ' ') as firstSignUpDate_rev
FROM xxxxxxx.xxxx
```

But the results are not correct . It should have added 11 hrs to the previous UTC time. Which is not correct as can be seen in the result,
[Bigquery results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPWES.png)

Answer (score 0):

the correct way is to

TIMESTAMP(SAFE_CAST(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', firstSignUpDate)as DATETIME))

Stripping T and Z is not the right way. It should be changed to TIMESTAMP format.

Finally, get the result with 10 hours being added to UTC

2021-09-16 00:36:30 UTC
2021-09-16T10:36:30